# Smoothness in projected Wannier function ( Construction of Smooth gauge)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, unitarity

I do not understand why the projected Wannier function can be localised in real space. Suppose there are $M$ bands of interest and the projector of those bands of interest is $P_{k} = \sum^{M}_{m =1 } | \psi_{mk} \rangle \langle \psi_{mk} | $ and a set of trial states $|g_{n} \rangle$ which is localised in real space. The first step of constructing the projected Wannier function is to projected the trial states into the band projector:
\begin{equation}
| \phi_{nk} \rangle = \sum^{M}_{m=1} | \psi_{mk} \rangle \langle \psi_{mk} | g_{n} \rangle . 
\end{equation}
[Marzari et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.5411) claim that the projected states $| \phi_{nk}\rangle$ typically smooth in k-space(c.f. eq(16) in that paper). I do not get this point if $| \psi_{nk} \rangle$ is degenerated.I try to compute the derivative of the projected state
\begin{equation}
\partial_{k} | \phi_{nk} \rangle  =  \sum^{M}_{m=1}  \Big[ (\partial_{k}\langle \psi_{mk} | g_{n} \rangle) |\psi_{mk} \rangle + \langle \psi_{mk} | g_{n} \rangle (\partial_{k} | \psi_{mk} \rangle ) \Big],
\end{equation}
the smoothness of  $| \phi_{nk} \rangle$ is determined by the second piece $\propto \partial_{k} | \psi_{mk} \rangle$. If we want $| \phi_{nk} \rangle$ to be smooth enough, I guess $\langle \psi_{mk} | g_{n} \rangle $ should be zero at $k$ in which $| \psi_{nk} \rangle$ is degenerate. But this seems too restrictive by the choice of the trial states $| g_{n} \rangle$. Could anyone help me to understand better on why the projected states is typically smooth and the mistakes that I made in my undertsanding.

Comment: In the second equation, why the degree of smoothness is determined by the second term. The first term is also a function of k

Comment: @ZhaoDazhuang, right, you are correct. I should say we need to be careful to the derivatives involving $| \psi_{nk} \rangle$ since it has non-analytical behaviour. So we need to choose the trial state $|g_n \rangle $ carefully such that it can iron out the non-analytical part of $| \psi_{nk} \rangle$. We should look at the first and second pieces for the smoothfulness.